# React - using memo in Functional Components to prevent rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, rendering, memoization

I have a component that calls a functional component n times.
My parent component holds a list and then it renders the list by mapping it and returning the functional component for each value. I want to prevent rerendering the functional components if their props remain the same when the state of the parent component changes. I am trying to use react.memo for this but the functional components are still rendering. The props in my functional component are:

```
ListElement.propTypes = {
  t: PropTypes.func, // react-i18next injected
  lng: PropTypes.string, // react-i18next injected
  conversationId: PropTypes.number,
  loggedInUserId: PropTypes.number,
  fromId: PropTypes.number,
  name: PropTypes.string,
  time: PropTypes.string,
  role: PropTypes.string,
  thumbnail: PropTypes.string,
  fromArchiveList: PropTypes.bool,
  hasChatStarted: PropTypes.bool,
  isPatient: PropTypes.bool,
  isNewMessage: PropTypes.bool,
  loggedInUserRole: PropTypes.string,
  isStarred: PropTypes.bool,
  unReadMessageCount: PropTypes.number,
};
```

The list is big, containing over 200 values. And I'm guessing this is why the profiler is showing my parent component taking a long time in redering. Each list element has unique keys as well. Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Do you add unique key attribute to each of  ListElement rendered ?

Comment: I am already passing unique keys. Should have mentioned it in the question. I will update it.

Comment: Maybe you could try to switch to PureComponent, just to make sure that memo isn't the issue ...

Comment: Btw. you can use clear-render to help you understand why the re-render happened

Comment: I will try doing that.

Comment: Whats clear-render?

Comment: Okay so using PureComponent stopped the unnecessary rerender! Yay! But now I have two questions: 1) Why didn't using keys prevent that? 2) Why didn't using memo prevent that?

Comment: clear-render is a package that helps you discover why rendering happened : https://dev.to/itwillwork/understand-react-better-4g50
I don't have much experience with memo, it's still new feature so it might have some quirks.

Comment: If you have a component that only has unique key and it's standard component, that doesn't necessary mean it won't re-render. PureComponent has shallow compare of all the props so it will prevent that from happening in simple cases (when props aren't deep objects etc.).

Comment: to answer those questions (which are legit btw), I think the relevant part of the parent render is needed along with the FC definition (with the react.memo part)